# Как сделать чтобы массив Лист (list) соответствовал двумерному зубчатому (ступенчатому) массиву arr[ ] [ ]

Tags: c#, массивы, случайные-числа

Есть двумерный зубчатый массив пример:

```
public string[][] arr = {
new string[] {значение0,значение1,значение2,значение3,значение4}
}
new string[] {значение5,значение6,значение7,значение8,значение9}
}
```

Нужно сделать рандомный выбор для строк и столбца. (это сделано)
Но потом нужно запомнить какое значение было выбрано. И больше чтобы рандом не выбирал это значение.
То есть (мой способ) нужно вычеркнуть нужный индекс из преобразованного в list (из массива arr)
например:

```
public int random = 3;
????Операция по правильному преобразованию массива в лист???(ЭТО ВОПРОС)

Код который делает всякое с данными в массиве (работа с даннымми);
```

Теперь нужно убрать этот рандом из выборки

```
list [0][ran].Remove; 

// итог: arr[0][] = {значение0,значение1,значение2,значение4} `(значение3 НЕТ)`
```

Остаётся лист с нужными нам значениями и по нему можно снова пускать рандом и он не попадёт на тоже самое значение.
Благодарствую за помощь!

Comment: Создать структуру с полями string и bool проблематично? В массиве у нужных элементов bool установите true (по умолчанию всегда стоит false), а в списке, после преобразования просто отбросить эти значения.

Comment: Если вам нужно получить элементы массива (это можно расширить и для случая двумерного массива) в случайном порядке, то проще перемешать элементы массива (или копии массива) и брать их по порядку, чем запоминать где-то какие элементы уже были взяты

Comment: Какую задачу вы этим решаете?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
void Main()
{
    var arr = new string[][] {
        new string[] {"значение0","значение1","значение2","значение3","значение4"},
        new string[] {"значение5","значение6","значение7","значение8","значение9"},
        };

    var list = arr.Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
    // это и есть лист листов
}
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а пояснить что и как в вашем коде, можно?

Comment: @Monomax Что именно вам хотелось узнать? Обычное приведение массива к списку через приведение типа Enumerable.

Comment: `Но потом нужно запомнить какое значение было выбрано. И больше чтобы рандом не выбирал это значение.`

Comment: Я всё сделал. (Я не сказал что я делаю на C# в Unity3D) Теперь я могу получать значение из листа. Окей можно и из него. Но я не совсем понимаю как мне удалить это место по индексу чтобы делать мой приславутый рандом)) я должен использовать resultlist.RemoveAt(индекс); ну я и записываю resultlist.RemoveAt([0][3]);
Я понимаю что пишу не верно, но как верно и что значит из примера https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018957/c-sharp-how-to-remove-item-from-list и как это адаптировать ко мне? (тоесть удалить как в зубчатом двумерном масссиве)
P.S. Огромное спасибо за отклик, очень неожиданно))))